# Without reloading the page, how do I display the image using the AJAX success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Without reloading the page, how do I display the image using the AJAX success function?

In my form, the `if ... else` condition is already there, and if the images exist in the database, the `if` condition will execute. The `else` condition will display the default image.

**form**

```
<form  id="data_form" action="#" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="photoContainer">
                    <a href="#" class="user-img">
                        <div class="profile-pic">
                            <?php if (empty($s_profile_imagee[0]) || empty($s_profile_imagee)) { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/default.jpg" class="img-user" alt="" width="150px;" height="150px;"/>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $s_profile_imagee; ?>" class="img-user" alt="" width="150px;" height="150px;"/>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if (empty($s_profile_imagee[0]) || empty($s_profile_imagee)) { ?>
                                <div id="profile-pic"><i class="fa fa-camera"><input type="file" class="fileInput" value="Add Photo" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="image"> Add Photo</i></div>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <div id="profile-pic"><i class="fa fa-camera"><input type="file" class="fileInput" value="Change Photo" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="image"> Change Photo</i></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**script**

```
<script>
              $(document).ready(function () {

                  $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

                      var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_profile_imagee',
                          data: form_data,
                          success: function (data)
                          {

                                 $('.photoContainer').text($("#image").val());

                          },
                          error: function ()
                          {
                              alert('failed');
                          }
                      });

                      e.preventDefault();
                  });

              });
        </script>
```

Comment: Inside ajax success, what are you trying with `$('.photoContainer').text($("#image").val());` ?

Comment: display images without page reload,i dont know its correct or not

Comment: Your code and your problem statement do not match itself

Comment: My problem is without page reload how to display the images in ajax success function above in my form  codeigniter code is there@MayankPandeyz

Comment: in 1st if else condition ,there is no images in database default image displaying, in 2nd if else condition there is no images in database  add photo button display in else part already image exist in database change button should be display @MayankPandeyz

Comment: without page reload how to display the image??

Comment: try this 1st: get the image path in `data`,  2nd: in `ajax success`  add this `$('#another-div').html("<img src='+data+'/>")` . Here **data** is image path

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 $(".img-user").setAttribute("src","<?php echo base_url();?>img/"+data);
```

Comment: again refreshing the page,i want without page reload image should be display @Jawahar Sharma

Comment: in your success function define it

Comment: You also don't mention e.preventdefault(); when yyour form is submitted